# Process Camera frames in background with IoT UWP and Raspberry pi

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to capture frames from a camera(usb or raspberrp pi camera) and process them in various ways. I've tried using the MediaCapture Object but it seems like it needs to be tied to the UI. The frames are not being viewed on a UI or saved on any type of storage. They will just be processed and thrown out.

```
var cameraDevice = await FindCameraDevice();

if (cameraDevice == null)
{
     IsInitialized = false;
     return false;
 }

var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
try
{
      await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
      IsInitialized = true;

      return true;
 }
catch{}
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?